# How to sum inner property of nested observable arrays, using Angular/RXJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, sum, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am having trouble getting the sum (or any reduction) of an inner number property of an Observable within another Observable.

I have an Observable array of "Account" objects (`Observable<AppAccount[]>`).

```
export interface AppAccount {
    _id?: string;
    name: string;
}
```

And an Observable array of "Balance" objects, each with an accountId. many balances can be associated with an account (sorted/filtered by date, but that piece is removed for brevity)

```
export interface AccountBalance {
    _id?: string;
    accountId: string;
    amount: number;
}
```

I have a helper method which returns just the last Balance object's Amount for a given Account.

```
getLastAmount(account: AppAccount): Observable<number> {
    return this.balanceService.balances$.pipe(
      map(balances => {
        let last = balances.filter(balance => {
          return balance.accountId === account._id;
        }).sort().pop();
        //console.log(last)
        return last ? last.amount : 0;
      }),
      tap(amount => console.log(`getLastAmount() => ${amount}`)),
    );
  }
```

Now I am trying to write a method which will loop through the Accounts, call getLastAmount() for each, and then sum them all and return an Observable. This is what I have managed so far:

```
getTotalBalance(accounts$: Observable<AppAccount[]>): Observable<number> {
    return accounts$.pipe(
      map(accounts => from(accounts)),
      mergeAll(),
      mergeMap(account => this.getLastAmount(account)),
      reduce((sum, current) => {
        console.log(`${sum} + ${current}`);
        return sum + current;
      }, 0)
    );
  }
```

But this seems to never return, and gets stuck in an infinite loop??

With just one account and one balance associated, with the balance having an 'amount' of '10', I get this from my console log: '0 + 10' over and over, and the network log also confirm it is calling getBalances() continuously.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way? Why does this RXJS pipe get stuck in a loop?

**EDIT**: I've made some changes based on picci's suggestions:

```
getTotalBalance(accounts$: Observable<AppAccount[]>): Observable<number> {
    return accounts$.pipe(
      map(accounts => accounts.map(account => this.getLastAmount(account))),
      concatMap(balances$ => { console.log('balances$', balances$); return forkJoin(balances$); }),
      tap(balances => console.log('balances', balances)),
      map(balances => balances.reduce(
        (amountSum, amount) => {
          console.log(`${amountSum} + ${amount}`)
          amountSum = amountSum + amount;
          return amountSum
        }, 0))
    );
  }
```

But this is still not returning, or the pipe is not completing?
I've made a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-nested-obsv
If you check the console output, it seems to not get any further than the forkJoin call...

Comment: Not sure about the infinite loop, but I think it does not return because you're using `reduce`, which will send the reduced value when the source(`accounts$` in this case), completes. If you want to receive values at each _reduce iteration_, you might want to use `scan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you could proceed like this

```
// somehow you start with the observable which returns the array of accounts
const accounts$: Observable<AppAccount[]> = getAccounts$()
// you also set the date you are interested in
const myDate: Moment = getDate()

// now you build the Observable<number> which will emit the sum of the last balance amounts
const amountSum$: Observable<number> = accounts$.pipe(
  // you transform an array of accounts in an array of Observable<number> representing the last Balance amount
  map((accounts: Account[]) => {
    // use the getLastAmount function you have coded
    return accounts.map(account => getLastAmount(account, myDate))
  }),
  // now we trigger the execution of the Observable in parallel using concatMap, which basically mean wait for the source Observable to complete
  // and forkJoin which actually executes the Observables in parallel
  concatMap(accounts$ => forkJoin(accounts$)),
  // now that we have an array of balances, we reduce them to the sum using the Array reduce method
  map(balances => balances.reduce(
    (amountSum, amount) => {
      amountSum = amountSum + amount;
      return amountSum
    }, 0)
  )
)

// eventually you subscribe to the amountSum$ Observable to get the result
amountSum$.subscribe({
  next: amountSum => console.log(`The sum of the last balances is: ${amountSum}`),
  error: console.err,
  complete: () => console.log("I am done")
})
```

There may be other combinations that bring to the same result, but this seems to work and can be checked in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cqc4ai).

If you are interested in some frequent patterns of RxJS with http calls, you may want to read [this blog](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: the line `concatMap(accounts$ => forkJoin(accounts$)),` is a useful trick, but the pipe does not seem to proceed past this rxjs function.
I've created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-nested-obsv

Comment: You simulate http with `BehaviorSubject` and not with the `of` function of RxJS. This causes the issue. Here the explanation. `forkJoin` emits when all its input Observables **complete**. The Observable returned by the http client emits one single value and then **completes**, so does the `of` function. A `Subject` never completes. So, if you pass a Subject into `forkJoin`, the result will never emit and the pipe will not proceed. Substitute `get balances$() { return this._balances$.asObservable(); }` with `get balances$() { return of(this.balances); }` in AccountBalanceService and it works.

Comment: Aha! the `BehaviourSubject`s never completing was exactly the issue. I didn't want to change the structure of my service, but from that hint I found that just using `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` works great!

Answer (score 1):

Well - first I don't think you should be using obsevables like that.

If you only need to the `totalBalance` you could use something like this (:

```
  private appAcount$ = from<AppAccount[]>([
    { _id: '1', name: 'user-1' },
    { _id: '2', name: 'user-2' },
    { _id: '3', name: 'user-3' },
  ]);

  // this would be your http call
  public getBalances(accountId: string): Observable<AccountBalance[]> {
    const ab = [
      { _id: '1', accountId: '1', amount: 100 },
      { _id: '2', accountId: '2', amount: 200 },
      { _id: '3', accountId: '2', amount: 300 },
      { _id: '4', accountId: '3', amount: 400 },
      { _id: '5', accountId: '3', amount: 500 },
      { _id: '6', accountId: '3', amount: 600 },
    ];

    return of(ab.filter(x => x.accountId === accountId));
  }

  lastAmounts$: Observable<AccountBalance[]> = this.appAcount$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(appAccount => 
        this.getBalances(appAccount._id)
          .pipe(
            // replace this with your date filter
            map(balances => [balances[balances.length - 1]]) 
          )
      ),
      scan((acc, c) => [ ...acc, ...c ])
    );

  totalBalance$ = this.lastAmounts$
    .pipe(
      map(x => x.reduce((p, c) => p += c.amount, 0))
    )
```

If you only need the total balance, the you could just subscribe to the totalBalance$ observable.

Let me say though, that I wouldn't recommend doing an HTTP call for each appAccount if you can do a batch fetch of all `AccountBalance`s of all the appAccounts you have - this way you can just use `combineLatest` for both `appAccounts$` and `balances$`.

Comment: I ended up following the advice of batch fetching the balances, and using combineLatest in a tricky way ended up doing the trick. Thanks!